# Jquery Ui Tabs: open created tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I have some tabs created with [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation) After I create a new tab using the example in the page I linked, I want that the newly created tab is shown. Is it possible, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding your new tab you can use `select` method of tabs plug-in with `length` method. Check my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/Atn3b/). I used same demo from [jQuery UI demo pages](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation).

```
$tabs.tabs( "add", "#tabs-" + tab_counter, tab_title ).tabs( 'select', $tabs.tabs('length') - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For recent versions (1.10.x) of jQuery UI, use the following. It's assumed that numberOfTabs is used to keep track of the number of tabs.

```
$tabs.tabs( "option", "active", numberOfTabs-1 );
```